# JSON GET Request with Python

Tags: python, json, get, request

I'm working in an application in Python. I have to do a GET request to get specific information. My code is somethings like that:

```
...
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(self.url)
header = {"Authorization":"Bearer "+self.token}
conn.request("GET","/data",headers=header)
...
```

and the JSON that I obtain is similar to this (you can observe that there are 2 big different part... this is just an example, in my application the parts are a lots).

```
[
{
    "createdAt": "2015-11-26T10:06:05.756Z", 
    "date": "2015-10-31T23:00:00.000Z", 
    "files": [], 
    "id": 1, 
    "metadata": {}, 
    "notes": "note impianto 1", 
    "parentSubject": {
        "code": "soggetto1", 
        "createdAt": "2015-11-26T10:05:38.765Z", 
        "id": 1, 
        "metadata": {}, 
        "notes": "note soggetto 1", 
        "personalInfo": 1, 
        "sex": "M", 
        "tags": null, 
        "type": 1, 
        "updatedAt": "2015-11-26T10:05:38.765Z"
    }
}, 
{
    "createdAt": "2015-11-26T10:06:36.684Z", 
    "date": "2015-11-01T23:00:00.000Z", 
    "files": [], 
    "id": 2, 
    "metadata": {}, 
    "notes": "note impianto 2", 
    "parentSubject": {
        "code": "soggetto1", 
        "createdAt": "2015-11-26T10:05:38.765Z", 
        "id": 1, 
        "metadata": {}, 
        "notes": "note soggetto 1", 
        "personalInfo": 1, 
        "sex": "M", 
        "tags": null, 
        "type": 1, 
        "updatedAt": "2015-11-26T10:05:38.765Z"
    }
}
]
```

If for example I make this request:

```
...
conn.request("GET","/data?id=1",headers=header)
...
```

I obviously get only the first part. The problem is that I don't want to get all data that have `id=1` but all data that have `code=soggetto1`. How can I do?

Comment: it seems you use some API. First check if API can send you only data with `"code": "soggetto1"`. If API can't do this then you have to get all data and find `"code": "soggetto1"` on your own.

Comment: yes, I'm using an API but the problem is that it doesn't have any official documentation because it is actually in development.

Comment: Ask developers if their API supports such requests

Comment: Are we supposed to guess how an unofficial undocumented (and actually unnamed) API works and which arguments it accepts ? No problem, just let me get my crystal ball, I'll back soon... More seriously: have you at least tried "/data?code=soggetto1" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If API can't do this then you have to get all data and find on your own.

In example I changed one code to "soggetto2"

```
data = '''[
{
    "createdAt": "2015-11-26T10:06:05.756Z", 
    "date": "2015-10-31T23:00:00.000Z", 
    "files": [], 
    "id": 1, 
    "metadata": {}, 
    "notes": "note impianto 1", 
    "parentSubject": {
        "code": "soggetto2", 
        "createdAt": "2015-11-26T10:05:38.765Z", 
        "id": 1, 
        "metadata": {}, 
        "notes": "note soggetto 1", 
        "personalInfo": 1, 
        "sex": "M", 
        "tags": null, 
        "type": 1, 
        "updatedAt": "2015-11-26T10:05:38.765Z"
    }
}, 
{
    "createdAt": "2015-11-26T10:06:36.684Z", 
    "date": "2015-11-01T23:00:00.000Z", 
    "files": [], 
    "id": 2, 
    "metadata": {}, 
    "notes": "note impianto 2", 
    "parentSubject": {
        "code": "soggetto2", 
        "createdAt": "2015-11-26T10:05:38.765Z", 
        "id": 1, 
        "metadata": {}, 
        "notes": "note soggetto 1", 
        "personalInfo": 1, 
        "sex": "M", 
        "tags": null, 
        "type": 1, 
        "updatedAt": "2015-11-26T10:05:38.765Z"
    }
}
]'''

#------------------------------------------------------

import json

j = json.loads(data)

results = []

for x in j:
    if x["parentSubject"]["code"] == "soggetto1":
        results.append(x)

print results
```

You can do this with list comprehension

```
results = [ x for x in j if x["parentSubject"]["code"] == "soggetto1" ]
```

or `filter()`

```
results = filter(lambda x:x["parentSubject"]["code"] == "soggetto1", j)
```